# NoMethodError: undefined method `switch_to'

Tags: android, ruby, mobile, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to automate a hybrid mobile app and I have been reading around and to automate a hybrid app I need to be using both the webview and native view.

Currently using appium_lib in conjunction with Ruby and Cucumber.
I run `@driver.available_contexts` and I get `=> ["NATIVE_APP", "WEBVIEW_59846.1"]`.

However when I try and switch to the webview `@driver.switch_to.context(webview)` I get the following error message

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `switch_to' for #<Appium::Driver:0x007f9c4f236958>
```

Can somebody please advise where I am going wrong? will I need a specific gem for this method?

Comment: Try the code @driver.set_context("WEBVIEW_59846.1")

Comment: Which Android OS version your device has?

Comment: @Vinod I am using android API 25 v7.1.1. I am now getting the message 
    Original error: unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 55.0.2883.0
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455517 
    (2c6d2707d8ea850c862f04ac066724273981e88f),platform=Mac OS X 
    10.12.5 x86_64)` do you have any suggestions? I am going to try and use API 26 and see if that works as thats the latest android API.

Comment: @ShafiqAhmedMalik  If you are using Android Version 6.0+ then you don't need to switch to webview. You can directly access the elements without switching. UIAutomator has that support with Android OS 6.0+.

Comment: @Vinod that great thanks for that!

Comment: @ShafiqAhmedMalik is it working now?

Comment: @Vinod it's kind of working. I am able to access elements by id but I am not able to access them by class or class name. So for example I can access on element by its id tag but when I search for the same element using the class or class _name tag I get this `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.` When locating elements in a hybrid app what locators can I use?

Comment: Also when I use link_text, partial_link_text, tag_name and css I get this error `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError: Locator Strategy 'link text' is not supported for this session`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error points out, there is no `switch_to` method in `Appium::Driver` class.

I think you are looking for [`set_context`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/appium/ruby_lib/Appium/Device#set_context-instance_method) method:

```
@driver.set_context(webview)
```

*This assumes that `webview` has been set with the proper value (i.e. `webview = "WEBVIEW_59846.1"`).*

Comment: I am using android API 25 v7.1.1. I am now getting the message 
    Original error: unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 55.0.2883.0
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455517 
    (2c6d2707d8ea850c862f04ac066724273981e88f),platform=Mac OS X 
    10.12.5 x86_64)` do you have any suggestions? I am going to try and use API 26 and see if that works as thats the latest android API.

Comment: @ShafiqAhmedMalik Unfortunatelly i'm not familiar with that error, so i won't be able to help you with that one. :( But, since the error is different, you could post a new question (they are free :) ) and the odds of getting an answer will be much higher (not everyone will check comments in answers, specially if the answer solves initial error).